# innerHTML doesn't work when using json.parse from localStorage

Tags: javascript, json

I tried to find an answer to this, but there are too many variables at play, so I hope some of you could explain to me what is happening here.
I have a basic HTML page with a div which has "issuesList" id.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body onload="foo();">
       <div id="issuesList"></div>
       <script src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my main.js:

```
function foo(){
    //var issues = JSON.parse(localStorge.getItem('issues'));
    var issuesList = document.getElementById('issuesList');
    document.getElementById('issuesList').setAttribute("style", "color:red;")
    issuesList.setAttribute("style", "color:red;");
    issuesList.innerHTML = 'XYZ';
}
```

The localStorage is empty, so it has no 'issues' object.

If I leave the commented line commented out, the issuesList DOM element will show XYZ written in red. If I uncomment it, then issuesList element remains empty. I don't understand why this is happening.

Also, if I add 'issues' to localStorage, and call again foo() method, still nothing is shown in the 'issuesList' element.

Thank you

Comment: What does your console look like when you leave the JSON parse line uncommented? any errors?  My guess is JSON.parse is failing, and so the rest of your code isn't executing.

Comment: An error will effectively stop JS in its tracks. If you're trying to parse `undefined`, that will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code, fixed:

```
function foo(){
    var issues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('issues') || "[]");
    var issuesList = document.getElementById('issuesList');
    issuesList.style.color = "red";
    issuesList.innerHTML = 'XYZ';
}
```

This will set `issues` to an empty array if there's nothing in `localStorage`. I also removed the superfluous line in the middle.
(You also had a typo: `localStorge`; always check your browser console)

Edit: it actually seems to mostly boil down to the typo. If the item isn't in localStorage, trying to get it returns `null`, and parsing that as JSON also returns `null`.

Additional note: `localStorage` can store objects; there's no need to `stringify` when storing and thus shouldn't be a need to `parse` when loading.